# How do you say "in time"?

Tags: translation, phrase-requests

I wanted to tell someone to escape so they don't waste their time waiting for me to beat a boss. (When their death timer reaches 0, they don't get credit for beating the boss, and my dps is slow...)

I said 逃げてください、ボスを倒すのに間に合わない, but I wasn't sure if it actually means: "I won't arrive in time to beat the boss" or if I did it right or wrong.

What I want to say is ", Please escape, I won't be able to beat the boss in time" or "Please escape, I won't be able to beat the boss before your timer runs out."

Comment: I think using どうせ works well with your situation. something like どうせ間に合わないから逃げた方がいいよ。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try saying:

> タイマーの時間切れの前に倒せそうもないので、戦闘から出て

- If there is an official Japanese word or a common Japanese colloquialism used to refer to the time in game, replace タイマー with that word.
- Since it's a video game, you don't need to worry as much about formalities like ください, unless you feel like you are asking for a lot. Most people don't use 丁寧語 while playing games in my experience.
- 時間切れ literally means "time is up"
- Volitional Form + もない is a grammar expresses that there is little observable evidence that something will happen. By combining this with the potential form of 倒す we get "I do not think I can defeat ", where you and the enemy are both contextually implied.
- I elected **not** to use 間に合う because the words necessary to make a sentence using 間に合う would for a slightly longer sentence, which I assumed you would rather not use. Refer to the example below:

  > 倒すのがタイマーの時間切れに間に合いそうもないので、戦闘から出て

Edits for shortening explanation and adding the last bullet and example sentence.